# Getting uninitialized constant Faker::String when attempting to set up rspec test in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have a UrlContent model and I am trying to write an rspec test for an API call to the index page for Json. However, whenever I run rspec, it gives me this error:

```
 Failure/Error: content { Faker::String }

 NameError:
   uninitialized constant Faker::String
```

Why would it give that error when faker for the attribute is already seemingly configured properly?

It is confusing to me because in my spec/factories/url_content.rb file I have:

require 'faker'

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :url_content do
    content { Faker::String }
  end
end
```

The specific rspec test I have setup is:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'faker'

RSpec.describe "UrlContents API", type: :request do

    before { FactoryBot.create_list(:url_content, 3) }

describe 'GET /url_contents' do
    before { get '/url_contents'}

    it 'returns a status code of 200' do 
        expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end

    it 'returns an array of content in JSON' do 
        json = JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true)

    end 

end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Faker::String` was added to the faker gem 9 days ago on [December 24](https://github.com/stympy/faker/commit/8bc7af1214c46f22283b009aacbcb124e3b600bb) and the latest version of faker(1.8.7) was published on [December 22](https://rubygems.org/gems/faker/versions/1.8.7). You'll have to use the version from Github in order to use `Faker::String`. Specify the git repository in your `Gemfile` as below:

```
gem 'faker', git: 'https://github.com/stympy/faker'
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Faker::String` was added to the ruby gem **9 days ago**](https://github.com/stympy/faker/commit/8bc7af1214c46f22283b009aacbcb124e3b600bb).

[The most recent gem version](https://rubygems.org/gems/faker), at the time of writing, is `1.8.7`; which was released on 22nd December (i.e. before `Faker::String` was added).

If you want to use that feature of the gem, you'll need to tell bundler to use the master branch of the repo:

```
gem 'faker', git: 'https://github.com/stympy/faker'
```

...or, build the gem locally from source.

```
git clone git@github.com:stympy/faker.git
rake install
```

This is quite unlucky that you've chosen to use an unreleased feature, on an actively maintained gem such as this.

However, in general you could check the [`changelog`](https://github.com/stympy/faker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) to see whether your gem version is sufficiently up-to-date; or, failing that, the git history directly.

You can also run `bundle open faker` within your project, and navigate the source code to see if your feature exists in the installed gem.